# PHP- is unable to read the other checked checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I stored the data in a supposed to be an array  but what happens is that only the last checked checkbox is the only one that is registered in the idSkills. This is the part of the code wherein the skills are displayed through a query in the database

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $skillName=$row['skillName']; 
?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $skillName; ?><br>
<?php 
        $i++;
    } 
?>
```

Here is the part where the loop unveil all of the selected checkbox

```
//QUERY TO INSERT
$conn = new mysqli($config['servername'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database']);       

$idSkills = $_GET['skills'];
if(empty($idSkills)) 
{
    echo("You didn't select any buildings.");
}
else
{
    $N = count($idSkills);

    echo("You selected $N door(s): ");
    echo("$idSkills[1] ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++) {
        echo "Skill ID: "
        $sql = "INSERT INTO volunteer_skills (idskill,idVolunteer) 
                VALUES ('$idSkills[$i]','$idVolunteer')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: echo `$sql` and you will see your errors. it might say "Array[0]...". Also if you use a GET parameter inside your query, you give users access to your entire database. You have to escape the values. See SQL Injection

Comment: What does `var_dump($idSkills);` return when selecting multiple checkboxes? @ibu OP should use prepared statements, not escaping imho

Comment: Why not just use a `foreach` loop instead of `for`?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use a prepared statement instead of substituting a variable into the SQL. But if you're going to do it this way, you need to use the correct syntax:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO volunteer_skills (idskill,idVolunteer) 
            VALUES ('{$idSkills[$i]}','$idVolunteer')";
```

You need to put `{}` around an array reference in order to get the variable inside the brackets to be evaluated. See the section on **Complex (curly) Syntax** in the PHP [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) documentation.

Comment: Seems you are mistaken here though,  [example](http://ideone.com/b4gRAP)

Comment: Wow, you're right. I always thought it didn't evaluate the index at all in simple syntax, because you can't put expressions there, and if you want to access an associative array element you have to leave off the quotes. But apparently it does allow a single variable in the index. The documentation is completely silent on this detail.